# Strange Google Fonts rendering issues

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-size, webfonts

I'm trying to use the Oxygen font from Google Fonts in my website, but I'm having strange problems with it.

Firstly, it doesn't seem to want to render at certain sizes, like I can't make it 19px. It will do 18px or 20px, but not 19px.

I also notice that the heights of the letters are borked. Take a look at the attached pic, how the 'S' is out. That's a screengrab of the font at 19pt. However, everything is 18px tall except the 'S' which is the one thing that sticks out to 19px.

[image: Strange Oxygen antialiasing]

And at larger sizes to this, other letters start antialiasing oddly too.

Whether I try ems or pxs or pts, I'm getting these glitches.

If you go to Google Fonts and search for Oxygen at the left and type in some text at larger sizes, it does the same thing, strange S's, etc. But strangely, if you search for specimens of this font in Google Images, it seems to render and antialias much better than this ([Oxygen specimens in Google Images](https://www.google.com/search?q=oxygen%20font&rlz=1C1CHMO_enZA468ZA469&biw=1920&bih=979&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj4wJeku7DKAhUEQBQKHYTrCiQQ_AUIBygB)). Any way to fix it or is this font broken at source?

Answer (score 0):

I hate to tell you but the font is broken at the source. It was obviously made unprofessionally or designed to be exactly that way. I'd recommend just using a new font or dealing with it as a regular user wont exactly mind it. Maybe a web analyst would but it's a nice font to a normal user.